# Where can I use "?attr"?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm making a dynamic theme by means of a themes.xml containing styles, with my own custom attributes.

Yes, I said custom, so I don't mean:

```
?android:attr/textColorSecondary
```

I mean:

```
?attr/custom
```

I have defined them in themes.xml, like

```
<style name="..." parent="....">
    <item name="custom">@color/foo_bar</item>
```

As well as in attrs.xml:

```
<attr name="custom" format="color" />
```

(For the sake of argument let's just say I'm only using colors for the attributes)

Now my question is, ultimately, can I do something like this...?

```
<!--colors.xml-->
<color name="color">?custom</color>
```

Of course that's pointless, it just links a few colors, but bear with me, it's just an example.

The same if I had a drawables.xml, or text color selectors? Where precisely can I call attributes? Just layouts?

What if I have:

```
<selector
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="?custom" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="?custom" />
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="?custom" />
  <item android:color="@color/foo" />
</selector>
```

Does that work?

I haven't found any documentation at all that told me I couldn't, nor have I found anything suggesting I can.

I don't see why I can't though, the attribute is the format "color".

Comment: In your selector or some layout that you need to color in xml? Yes. In your colors.xml? Nope, only color hex codes there.

Comment: @freddieptf Using `?attr` in selectors, more precisely in the `drawable` folder, will only work on devices running api-version 21+. On previous version an exception will be thrown. So it's more a "nope" there as well. ;)

Comment: @reVerse that's quite strange. What if it's a selector outside of /drawables? Such as if the selector is directly in the layout xml, or if it's in a different folder, like /res/xml?

Comment: And thanks to you both!

Comment: @JackGreenlee Then it won't be recognized as a selector. A selector needs to be in the `color` or `drawable` directory.